# Return a XDocument generated XML file to browser in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I created a XML 1.0 file using XDocument class in .NET framework.

The question is: how do I return the generated file to the browser to allow the user to save it?

I have `var generatedXMLfile = generateXml(Parameters param)` this methods returns a XDocument class instance with my XML. 
Then I need to take the `generatedXMLfile` and return it to the browser as an XML file. 
I don't want to write a file in the server and then pass it to the browser, maybe it would be better to 
save a temp file in memory.

Thank You.

Comment: Simply use ToString();  So you XDocument doc  would be doc.ToString();  Then take string and add to your html data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert it to a string and then return the string as an `application/json` content type.

You can convert the document to a string like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();  

var tr = new StringWriter(sb);  
xmlDoc.Save(tr);  
var xmlToSendToClient = sb.ToString();
```